# How can I bind a variable to a value in widget

Tags: jupyter-lab, jupyter-widget

What is the simplest way to bind a variable to a value in widget?

For eg.

```
x = 3
from ipywidgets import widgets
input_text = widgets.Text()
input_text
```

Here in the text box ("input_text"), I need to refer to the variable x. Such that input_text.value = 3.

How can I do it?

I could not find a way to do it.

Comment: Why input_text.value = 3 isn't an option?